# git keeps checking out ignored file

Tags: git

I have a config file which was committed earlier by mistake. I added it to .gitignore and also did a `git update-index --assume-unchanged`, but when I do a `git checkout -- .`, it reverts it back to an older, committed version. How can I ignore it completely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a file is already being tracked (has been committed, and specifically exists in your `HEAD` commit), it cannot be ignored via `.gitignore`. If you want to prevent it showing up in future checkouts, you need to `git rm --cached <file>; git commit -m "stop tracking <file>"`. If also removing the copy in your working directory is acceptable, you can drop the `--cached` option to `git rm`.